# Landscape Mode in iOS 8+ not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a couple of older Cocos2d games that, when updating, I noticed appear truncated upon launch. Having found other answers here on StackOverflow I am still having issues.

The workaround I currently use is;

Inside `AppDelegate.m` I am using

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
    navController_.view.transform = transform;
```

And setting the device orientation to Portrait & Portraitupsidedown - even though the game is Landscape.
This is a dirty fix, and brings it's own set of issues, such as UIAlert views not appearing at the correct orientation, as well as the screen not rotating landscape upside down (unless you hold it portraitupsidedown) which gets confusing, and pretty sure it is against Apple's review rules and just make the whole workaround useless really.

Effectively I need to trick it so that I can enable Landscape mode rather than Portrait, yet rotate the screen on launch, has anyone managed this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this in AppDelegate.m class

   - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
     {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
     }
2. Project file -> 'Targets' -> Choose you orientation to Landscape

Comment: makes no difference at all.

Comment: Both options? You want the app to launch in landscape mode right? What XCode version are you using?

Comment: 8.2.1 and the code you give me also presents a yellow error;

`conflicting return type in implementation of 'application;supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow':UIInterfaceOrientationMask(aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask) vs 'NSUInteger (aka unsigned int'  `

Comment: No difference, the  issue I believe to be related to COCOS2D recognising screen dimensions in landscape